# RelativeLayout setBackgroundDrawable is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

my question : RelativeLayout setBackgroundDrawable is not working

no error, only not change or set

my code

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_img1"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.noiseframe.MainActivity" >
```

**MainActivity.java**

Member Variable

```
Resources img1R;
Resources img2R;
Resources img3R;
Resources img4R;
Resources img5R;

Drawable img1D;
Drawable img2D;
Drawable img3D;
Drawable img4D;
Drawable img5D;
```

onCreate

```
relative = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

img1R = getResources();
img2R = getResources();
img3R = getResources();
img4R = getResources();
img5R = getResources();

img2D = img2R.getDrawable(R.drawable.main_img2);

relative.setBackgroundDrawable(img2D);
```

Finally, the handler will change the background
but..In writing anywhere, Background of my main activities are not change..

Thank you for your kindness

Back to the first code
now code

```
    RelativeLayout relativelayout;
    relativelayout = new RelativeLayout(this);  
    relativelayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_img2));
```

no error! no inflating !
but back image is not change TT...

Comment: Try relative.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_img2); -instead of all that you have written.

Comment: MainActivity.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.main_img2)); is red line on main_img2

Comment: and .. view using -> red line on the main_img2

Comment: So you are inflating a new layout and setting a background in it. What are you doing with the `relative` layout later, for example are you putting it on screen anyway?

Comment: The post was modified. That was the original code. I do not figure this error is not changed @laalto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use those many variables. You can directly give the background image like this.

```
relative.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.image_name));
```

and I have one more question if you are in your MainActivity and if you have already used setContentView for your xml file. why are you inflating the xml file there?

Comment: Find the wrong part,Create increasing detail  .The first short. I'll try your code

Comment: If you do not inflating, getDrawable (R.id. resource not found) 
When coding a getDrawable (R.id.main_img2) red line on main_img2

Comment: try.. MainActivity.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.main_img2)); but main_img2 is redline

Comment: resource not found @Sid

Comment: can i see your full code. IF possible drop me your code in an email to mahesh.venkat27@gmail.com

Comment: Sadly, this project is confidential TT.. but @Sid , Revised gone red line!  relativelayout = new RelativeLayout(this);  
  relativelayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_img2));       but setbackgrounddrawable is not working..